# Press Enter to Continue in C

Tags: c, input

How can you do a "Press Enter to Continue" in C?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
printf("Press enter to continue\n");
char enter = 0;
while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') { enter = getchar(); }
printf("Thank you for pressing enter\n");
```

Comment: `enter` should be an int. Being a char there's no way to differentiate between EOF or a real character.

Answer (score 23):

```
printf("Press Enter to Continue");
while( getchar() != '\n' );
```

A check for '\r' is nice for ultimate portability, but really only matters if you are targeting Mac OS v9 or older (OS-X, Unix & Windows all use either '\n' or, for windows, '\r\n')