# C - Press Enter to Continue?

Tags: c

```
void clrKyb(void)
{
    char c[30];

    scanf("%s",c);

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if(c[i] == '\n'){
            i = 30;
        }
    }
}

void pauses(void)
{
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue:");
    clrKyb();
}
```

Hello, I am stuck on my "pauses" function. Pressing ENTER to continue does not work?

Comment: `%s` tries to read a word. If you just press Enter, there's no word, so it will keep waiting.

Comment: `scanf` is unsafe. Use `scanf_s` instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: @Dai: Isn't that Microsoft-specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate(s)? [Press Enter to Continue in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406421/press-enter-to-continue-in-c?rq=1) and ["Press Any Key to Continue" function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801483/press-any-key-to-continue-function-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: @KeithThompson if they were then they aren't any more: they're standardised in C11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: @Dai: Standardized, but optional, and glibc in particular doesn't implement them.

Answer (score 3):

Just use getchar(), it returns the first character read from stdin and waits until ENTER.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void clrKyb(void) {
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {};
}
void pause(void) {
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue.");
    clrKyb();
}
```

I have a feeling this is homework. Please, next time, let us know beforehand so we can provide guidance rather than answers.

Comment: I also need it to read something longer than 1 character too. For example "abcd".

Comment: @user3013760 But do you actually need that input returned? Because your example doesn't do that. This function is able to detect more than 1 characters and an enter, but only returns the first. you don't need to check if the return of getchar() is '\n', if it continues, you know the enter key was hit.

Comment: It gets returned in other functions, which all works. I'm only stuck on 'pauses'. Pressing <Enter> just continues to the rest of the code.

Comment: @user3013760 So you DON'T need to know the actual contents of what was entered before ENTER? In that case, this solution will work. See my edit to my comment.

Comment: If the user types `abcd` followed by Return, `getchar()` will read just the `a`. The reset of the line, including the trailing `'\n'`, will be left in stdin to be read by the next input operation.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Thanks, I'm editing my answer to include your requirements and a new solution I found elsewhere on stack exchange.

Comment: @dshus: If you found a solution elsewhere on Stack Overflow, the question should probably be marked as a duplicate.